# RadioButtonList SelectedItem always first one

Tags: c#, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I am using simple radiobuttonlist with four items, I have enabled viewstate and postback but whatever option I choose it always return first value.

Here is the code:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
     EnableViewState="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Changed" ID="rbSlots">
</asp:RadioButtonList>


ListItem item = new ListItem(starthour + " - " + stophour + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["LastName"].ToString(), ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["xavid"] + "¤" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["xuserid"]);
```

and I have RadCalendar, on which SelectedDateChanged Event I populate the radlist

Comment: Showing us what you have already would be good help!

Answer (score 2):

Vibralux thanks for reply!

I fixed it now, it was a mistake that my VALUE for list items which I was generating were not unique, so I just assigned unique values to Listitem and it started working fine.

Regards